# Matching an optional number in a Lua pattern

Tags: regex, lua, lpeg

I'm parsing the output from the diff3 command and some lines look like this:

```
1:1,2c
2:0a
```

I am interested in the numbers in the middle. Its either a single number or a pair of numbers separated by commas. With regexes I can capture them both like this:

```
/^\d+:(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?[ac]$/
```

What is the simplest equivalent in Lua? I can't pass a direct translation of that regex to string.match because of the optional second number.

Comment: The comma acts as a separator between the first number (which is always present) and the second number (which is optional)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: This question is for Lua, which doesnt have a standard regexes in the stdlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lua patterns, you could use the following:

```
^%d+:(%d+),?(%d*)[ac]$
```

Example:

```
local n,m = string.match("1:2,3c", "^%d+:(%d+),?(%d*)[ac]$")
print(n,m) --> 2    3

local n,m = string.match("2:0a", "^%d+:(%d+),?(%d*)[ac]$")
print(n,m) --> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using lua patterns too:

```
local num = str:match '^%d+:(%d+),%d+[ac]$' or str:match '^%d+:(%d+)[ac]$'
```

Comment: This one-liner doesn't work if I need to capture both numbers as in `local n,m = ...`. Copying and pasting the pattern is a simple thing that went right over my head though.

Comment: @hugomg You can set the second number group to be `%d-` (or `%d*`) to match `0` occurrences as well.